# Can data be backup to iCloud but does not sync?

Tags: backup, synchronization, icloud

I have a developer coding an app for me and they claim that some photo data is being backed-up to the iCloud, but this data does not sync and when A restore is done form the iCloud no picture data is restored.

My question is, is it even possible to do an iCloud backup without having the data sync across devices?  The definition of iCloud seems to me to say that if it is in the iCloud it is synced.  Can someone confirm?